# ColdFusion looping over an array with an empty/undefined field

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am downloading data from an API from one of our vendors.  The data is an array but some of the fields are empty and come over as `undefined`.  I am able to get most of the information out with a loop but when I add the field "notes" it fails with the error of:

**"Element notes is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression. The specific sequence of files included or processed is:**

> C:\websites\Fire\Reports\xml_parse\Crewsense_payroll_loop.cfm, line:
>   21 "

When I look at the dump I see that the field shows as "undefined".  I've run out of ideas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've included the entire code and a link to the dump showing the array.

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.crewsense.com/v1/payroll? access_token=as;lkdfj;alskdfj;laksdfj&token_type=bearer&start=2019-01-05%2019:00:00&end=2019-01-06%2007:59:00" method="GET" resolveurl="YES" result="result">
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>

<cfset ApiData = deserializeJSON(result.filecontent)>

<cfset API_ArrayLength = arraylen(ApiData)>

    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to=#API_ArrayLength#>    

    #i# #ApiData[i]["name"]#
        #ApiData[i]["employee_id"]#
        #ApiData[i]["start"]#
        #ApiData[i]["end"]#
        #ApiData[i]["total_hours"]#
        #ApiData[i]["work_type"]#
        #ApiData[i]["work_code"]#
        #ApiData[i]["user_id"]#
        #ApiData[i]["notes"]#  <---Fails here when added--->

        <cfset i = i+1>
    <br>
    </cfloop>   

    <cfdump var="#ApiData#">

</cfoutput>
```

[Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkhgE.png)

Comment: In addition to MiguelF's comments, consider using an "array" loop, instead of from/to, to simplify the code

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with data structures that have optional elements you will need to check for their existence before trying to access them. Otherwise you will get that error. I have added a snippet with an `if` condition utilizing the [structKeyExists()](https://cfdocs.org/structkeyexists) function to your code as an example.

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.crewsense.com/v1/payroll? access_token=as;lkdfj;alskdfj;laksdfj&token_type=bearer&start=2019-01-05%2019:00:00&end=2019-01-06%2007:59:00" method="GET" resolveurl="YES" result="result">
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>

    <cfset ApiData = deserializeJSON(result.filecontent)>

    <cfset API_ArrayLength = arraylen(ApiData)>

    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to=#API_ArrayLength#>    

    #i# #ApiData[i]["name"]#
        #ApiData[i]["employee_id"]#
        #ApiData[i]["start"]#
        #ApiData[i]["end"]#
        #ApiData[i]["total_hours"]#
        #ApiData[i]["work_type"]#
        #ApiData[i]["work_code"]#
        #ApiData[i]["user_id"]#
        <cfif structKeyExists(ApiData[i],"notes")>
            #ApiData[i]["notes"]#  <!--- Show 'notes' if it exists --->
        <cfelse>
            'notes' is not available  <!--- Do something here (or not) --->
        </cfif>

        <cfset i = i+1>
        <br>
    </cfloop>   

    <cfdump var="#ApiData#">

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: To make this easier, you can add the optional keys as a list, then loop over that as well, checking for each list element instead of writing an individual `structKeyExists()` for each key. You can adjust this list as needed in the future will less code changes. 3rd option would be an array of structs so you can list the optional keys with their related defaults as needed.

Comment: Yes good points @AdrianJ.Moreno. I was just trying to show the OP the basic idea of how to check the structure before accessing it.